# Inquiry about Undefined array

Tags: javascript

As I have revised on the codes, I have found that the code that I wrote cannot function normally but the words shown are always “undefined”, but I have checked many times that the code seems perfect. Could you mind to have a look and check for me? That really confused me a lot...Thank you very much. I appreciate your help very much.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<style>
body{display:block; 
margin:auto;
text-align:center;}
canvas{border:1px solid black;}
</style>
<script>
var canvas;
var ctx;
var timer;
var words=["canoe","buddha","elephant","dice"];//
var words=["canoe","buddha","elephant","dice"];
var answerIndex=-1;
var answer_x=-1;
var answer_y=-1;
var plate_x=-1;
var plate_y=-1;
var score=0;
function draw()
{ ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height-10);
//canvas=document.getElementById("Canvas");
//ctx=canvas.getcontext("2d")
answer_x+=3;
answer_y+=3;

var answer=words[answerIndex];
ctx.font="20px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle="black";
ctx.fillText(answer,answer_x,answer_y);
var distance=answer_x-plate_x;
document.getElementById("plate_x").innerHTML=plate_x;
document.getElementById("word_x").innerHTML=answer_x;
document.getElementById("dist").innerHTML=distance;
if (answer_y>=plate_y)
{
 clearInterval(timer);
 if ((distance<50) && (distance>-50))
 {
 document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Bravo!";
 score++;
 document.getElementById("score").innerHTML=score;
 }
 else 
  {
 document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Game over!";
  }
 }
}
function getRandomIndex()
{var random_number=Math.random*words.length;
var random_int=Math.floor(random_number);
return random_int;
}

function play()
{
canvas=document.getElementById("Canvas");
ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
answerIndex = getRandomIndex();
 var answer = words[answerIndex];
 var imageFileName = answer + ".jpg";
 document.getElementById("myPic").src = imageFileName;
 
answer_x=0;
answer_y=0;
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
 plate_x=0;
 plate_y=canvas.height-10;
 ctx.fillStyle="blue";
 ctx.fillRect(plate_x,plate_y,50,10);
 clearInterval(timer);
timer=setInterval("draw()",100);
}


function moveleft()
{ ctx.clearRect(plate_x,plate_y,50,10);

if(plate_x>0)
{plate_x-=20;}

ctx.fillStyle="blue";
ctx.fillRect(plate_x,plate_y,50,10);

}
function moveright()
{ ctx.clearRect(plate_x,plate_y,50,10);

if(plate_x<(canvas.width-50))
{plate_x+=20;}

ctx.fillStyle="blue";
ctx.fillRect(plate_x,plate_y,50,10);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Catch the word!</h1>
<img id="myPic" alt="no pic" src="" width="200"/><br/>
<canvas id="Canvas" width="300" height="250"></canvas>
<br/><button onclick="play()">Play</button>
<button onclick="moveleft()">&larr;</button>
<button onclick="moveright()">&rarr;</button>
<p id="message">Move to catch the word!</p>
<p id="score"></p>
<p>Plate X-coordinate:</p><p id="plate_x"></p>
<p>Word X-coordinate:</p><p id="word_x"></p>
<p>Distance:</p><p id="dist"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"I wonder if there're anything that I can locate the bug more precisely"* - Yes!  Your web browser has built-in debugging tools.  (Well, it should anyway.  If it doesn't, get a better web browser.)  With these tools you can set breakpoints in the code to pause live execution and step through the code, line by line, as it executes.  You can observe the runtime values and behaviors and identify *specifically* where the functionality first deviates from what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `getRandomIndex()` function, you forgot the parenthesis after `Math.random`, which accesses `random` as a property rather than a method. So `Math.random` in your formula should be `Math.random()` instead.

Your current code doesn't work because your `getRandomIndex()` function returns `NaN`:

```
function getRandomIndex() {
  var random_number = Math.random * words.length;
  var random_int = Math.floor(random_number);

  console.log(Math.random);
  // ƒ random() { [native code] }

  console.log(random_number);
  // NaN

  console.log(random_int);
  // NaN

  return random_int;
}
```

If you change your current code to use `Math.random()` instead, then your `getRandomIndex()` function will return the random integer value you are expecting:

```
function getRandomIndex() {
  var random_number = Math.random() * words.length; // changed code
  var random_int = Math.floor(random_number);

  console.log(Math.random());
  // 0.40108128192401526 (of course this value will change each time)

  console.log(random_number);
  // 3.613675793700807 (of course this value will change each time)

  console.log(random_int);
  // 3 (of course this value will change each time)

  return random_int;
}
```

To follow on the comment from [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328193/david), in the future if you run into something like this you could always `console.log()` some of the values from the function that is not returning the expected output. This will help you run down your issue when there are no errors in the console.

Comment: How can we find the problem of Math.random by using console.log()? Previously, I added console.log() under the function getRandomIndex() {  } and the browser just tells me there is a problem in line 66  and 106 line. However, line 66 and line 106  are actually perfect.    Line 66: document.getElementById("myPic").src = imageFileName;   Line 106: <br/><button onclick="play()">Play</button>.  However, the browser does not tell us the problem of Math.random. Could you mind telling me how to find it out by using console.log() ? Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @JackyChau - edited the answer to provide more detailed example of how you can use `console.log()` to see what is wrong with your `getRandomIndex()` function.

Comment: Oh. I see. Thank you very much for your detailed and meticulous reply. Based on what you said, I have understood now.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable ctx is undefined because you define ctx in the function play().

and at the beginning of your script you are declaring all your variables but you leave ctx and canvas empty

```
var canvas; //<------ You leave canvas empty
var ctx; //<------ You leave ctx empty
var timer;
var words = ["canoe", "buddha", "elephant", "dice"];
var words = ["canoe", "buddha", "elephant", "dice"];
var answerIndex = -1;
var answer_x = -1;
var answer_y = -1;
var plate_x = -1;
var plate_y = -1;
var score = 0;
```

At the play function you assign a value to it.

```
function play() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); //<---- Here you add a value
  answerIndex = getRandomIndex();
  var answer = words[answerIndex];
  var imageFileName = answer + ".jpg";
  document.getElementById("myPic").src = imageFileName;

  answer_x = 0;
  answer_y = 0;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  plate_x = 0;
  plate_y = canvas.height - 10;
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(plate_x, plate_y, 50, 10);
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setInterval("draw()", 100);
}
```

But that value will only be available within that function.

and all your other functions also use ctx!
In the folowing code block I clarified all the places where it went wrong and where it didn't go wrong.

```
var canvas;
var ctx; //<--- here you leave it empty
var timer;
var words = ["canoe", "buddha", "elephant", "dice"];
var words = ["canoe", "buddha", "elephant", "dice"];
var answerIndex = -1;
var answer_x = -1;
var answer_y = -1;
var plate_x = -1;
var plate_y = -1;
var score = 0;

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height - 10); //<---  Here you are calling ctx but ctx is not defined!
  //canvas=document.getElementById("Canvas");
  //ctx=canvas.getcontext("2d") //Here you are randomly identifying ctx but you made a comment of it...
  answer_x += 3;
  answer_y += 3;

  var answer = words[answerIndex];
  ctx.font = "20px Arial"; //<---  Here you are calling ctx but ctx is not defined!
  ctx.fillStyle = "black"; //<---  Here you are calling ctx but ctx is not defined!
  ctx.fillText(answer, answer_x, answer_y); //<---  Here you are calling ctx but ctx is not defined!
  var distance = answer_x - plate_x;
  document.getElementById("plate_x").innerHTML = plate_x;
  document.getElementById("word_x").innerHTML = answer_x;
  document.getElementById("dist").innerHTML = distance;
  if (answer_y >= plate_y) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    if ((distance < 50) && (distance > -50)) {
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Bravo!";
      score++;
      document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Game over!";
    }
  }
}

function getRandomIndex() {
  var random_number = Math.random * words.length;
  var random_int = Math.floor(random_number);
  return random_int;
}

function play() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); // <--- here you correctly identified ctx
  answerIndex = getRandomIndex();
  var answer = words[answerIndex];
  var imageFileName = answer + ".jpg";
  document.getElementById("myPic").src = imageFileName;

  answer_x = 0;
  answer_y = 0;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //<---- So this can be executed and is NOT undefined
  plate_x = 0;
  plate_y = canvas.height - 10;
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue"; //<---- So this can be executed and is NOT undefined
  ctx.fillRect(plate_x, plate_y, 50, 10); //<---- So this can be executed and is NOT undefined
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setInterval("draw()", 100);
}


function moveleft() {
  ctx.clearRect(plate_x, plate_y, 50, 10); //<---  Here you are calling ctx but ctx is not defined!

  if (plate_x > 0) {
    plate_x -= 20;
  }

  ctx.fillStyle = "blue"; //<---  Here you are calling ctx but ctx is not defined!
  ctx.fillRect(plate_x, plate_y, 50, 10); //<---  Here you are calling ctx but ctx is not defined!

}

function moveright() {
  ctx.clearRect(plate_x, plate_y, 50, 10); //<---  Here you are calling ctx but ctx is not defined!

  if (plate_x < (canvas.width - 50)) {
    plate_x += 20;
  }

  ctx.fillStyle = "blue"; //<---  Here you are calling ctx but ctx is not defined!
  ctx.fillRect(plate_x, plate_y, 50, 10); //<---  Here you are calling ctx but ctx is not defined!

}
```

SO the solution will be to declare ctx and canvas at the beginning like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas"); //<----- Like this
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); //<------ Like this
var timer;
var words = ["canoe", "buddha", "elephant", "dice"];
var words = ["canoe", "buddha", "elephant", "dice"];
var answerIndex = -1;
var answer_x = -1;
var answer_y = -1;
var plate_x = -1;
var plate_y = -1;
var score = 0;
```

But in order for this to work you will need the remove the script from the head and place it all the way to the bottom of your body like this:

```
<html>
    <head>

       Remove your script from here
    </head>
    <body>
       All the contents of your body           

       And place your script here
    </body>
</html>
```

or declare ctx at the beginning of every function that needs it like this:

```
var canvas;
var ctx;
var timer;
var words = ["canoe", "buddha", "elephant", "dice"];
var words = ["canoe", "buddha", "elephant", "dice"];
var answerIndex = -1;
var answer_x = -1;
var answer_y = -1;
var plate_x = -1;
var plate_y = -1;
var score = 0;

function draw() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas"); //<----- declare canvas here
  ctx = canvas.getcontext("2d"); // <--- declare ctx here
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height - 10);
  answer_x += 3;
  answer_y += 3;

  var answer = words[answerIndex];
  ctx.font = "20px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillText(answer, answer_x, answer_y);
  var distance = answer_x - plate_x;
  document.getElementById("plate_x").innerHTML = plate_x;
  document.getElementById("word_x").innerHTML = answer_x;
  document.getElementById("dist").innerHTML = distance;
  if (answer_y >= plate_y) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    if ((distance < 50) && (distance > -50)) {
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Bravo!";
      score++;
      document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Game over!";
    }
  }
}

function getRandomIndex() {
  var random_number = Math.random * words.length;
  var random_int = Math.floor(random_number);
  return random_int;
}

function play() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas"); //<----- declare canvas here
  ctx = canvas.getcontext("2d"); // <--- declare ctx here
  answerIndex = getRandomIndex();
  var answer = words[answerIndex];
  var imageFileName = answer + ".jpg";
  document.getElementById("myPic").src = imageFileName;

  answer_x = 0;
  answer_y = 0;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  plate_x = 0;
  plate_y = canvas.height - 10;
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(plate_x, plate_y, 50, 10);
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setInterval("draw()", 100);
}


function moveleft() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas"); //<----- declare canvas here
  ctx = canvas.getcontext("2d"); // <--- declare ctx here
  ctx.clearRect(plate_x, plate_y, 50, 10);

  if (plate_x > 0) {
    plate_x -= 20;
  }

  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(plate_x, plate_y, 50, 10);

}

function moveright() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas"); //<----- declare canvas here
  ctx = canvas.getcontext("2d"); // <--- declare ctx here
  ctx.clearRect(plate_x, plate_y, 50, 10);

  if (plate_x < (canvas.width - 50)) {
    plate_x += 20;
  }

  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(plate_x, plate_y, 50, 10);

}
```

Also please read the comments of other people too because they might note other mistakes that I didn't see

Comment: @benvc is also right edit these two mistakes and you will be good

Comment: However, after I corrected the Math.random into Math.random() , the website can function perfectly. So, does it mean adding declaration to ctx in each function is not necessary?